# O que são entities HTML?

Tags: html, terminologia, característica-linguagem

Frequentemente vejo uns códigos muito loucos, no meio das *tags* HTML, e pesquisando cai nesse termo *entities*, então surgiram as dúvidas:

O que são Entities HTML e quando devo usá-las?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

É um código que representa um caractere, ele inicia com `&` e termina com `;`. O que vai no meio é o nome da entidade, do caractere. Podemos chamar de **caracteres nomeados**.

Ele é usado principalmente com escape em caracteres que não podem ser facilmente colocados dentro do HTML. Um caso bem típico é o sinal de menor e maior (`<` e `>`) que são usadas para *tags*. Aspas também (`"` e `'`). Obviamente o próprio `&` precisa ser representado como entidade. Espaço é outro comum já que o HTML não considera vários espaços em sequência como a intenção correta e acaba imprimindo um só, obrigado o uso do `&nbsp;` para produzir o resultado desejado.

Outros são usados porque não costuma ter uma forma fácil de representá-los por meios normais. Símbolos matemáticos e acentuação são exemplos. Teve época que isso era muito importante porque o *source* da página podia estar em uma codificação que não permitia todos os caracteres possíveis. Hoje é raro isso ocorrer porque é possível usar Unicode facilmente, mas ainda é possível usar se for mais adequado.

Uma [lista completa e oficial](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/named-character-references.html).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu posso utilizar "entities" apenas no HTML ou outras tecnologias também podem fazer de uso?

Comment: Não sei de que tecnologias está falando, mas provavelmente só HTML. exceto se houver especificação que essa tecnologia tenha também.